# How to overwrite a scoped service with a decorated implementation?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, integration-testing, xunit

I'm trying to write an ASP.NET Core 2.2 integration test, where the test setup decorates a specific service that would normally be available to the API as a dependency. The decorator would give me some additional powers I'd need in my integration tests to intercept calls to the underlying service, but **I can't seem to properly decorate a normal service in `ConfigureTestServices`**, as my current setup will give me:

> An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> No service for type 'Foo.Web.BarService' has been registered.

To reproduce this, I've just used VS2019 to create a fresh ASP.NET Core 2.2 API `Foo.Web` project...

```
// In `Startup.cs`:
services.AddScoped<IBarService, BarService>();
```

```
public interface IBarService
{
    string GetValue();
}
```

```
public class BarService : IBarService
{
    public string GetValue() => "Service Value";
}
```

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class ValuesController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly IBarService barService;

    public ValuesController(IBarService barService)
    {
        this.barService = barService;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult<string> Get()
    {
        return barService.GetValue();
    }
}
```

...and a companion xUnit `Foo.Web.Tests` project I [utilize a `WebApplicationfactory<TStartup>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/test/integration-tests?view=aspnetcore-2.2#aspnet-core-integration-tests)...

```
public class DecoratedBarService : IBarService
{
    private readonly IBarService innerService;

    public DecoratedBarService(IBarService innerService)
    {
        this.innerService = innerService;
    }

    public string GetValue() => $"{innerService.GetValue()} (decorated)";
}
```

```
public class IntegrationTestsFixture : WebApplicationFactory<Startup>
{
    protected override void ConfigureWebHost(IWebHostBuilder builder)
    {
        base.ConfigureWebHost(builder);

        builder.ConfigureTestServices(servicesConfiguration =>
        {
            servicesConfiguration.AddScoped<IBarService>(di
                => new DecoratedBarService(di.GetRequiredService<BarService>()));
        });
    }
}
```

```
public class ValuesControllerTests : IClassFixture<IntegrationTestsFixture>
{
    private readonly IntegrationTestsFixture fixture;

    public ValuesControllerTests(IntegrationTestsFixture fixture)
    {
        this.fixture = fixture;
    }

    [Fact]
    public async Task Integration_test_uses_decorator()
    {
        var client = fixture.CreateClient();
        var result = await client.GetAsync("/api/values");
        var data = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        result.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
        Assert.Equal("Service Value (decorated)", data);
    }
}
```

The behavior kind of makes sense, or at least I *think* it does: I suppose that the little factory lambda function (`di => new DecoratedBarService(...)`) in `ConfigureTestServices` cannot retrieve the concrete `BarService` from the `di` container because it's in the main service collection, not in the test services.

How can I make the default ASP.NET Core DI container provide decorator instances that have the original concrete type as their inner service?

**Attempted solution 2:**

I've tried the following:

```
protected override void ConfigureWebHost(IWebHostBuilder builder)
{
    base.ConfigureWebHost(builder);

    builder.ConfigureTestServices(servicesConfiguration =>
    {
        servicesConfiguration.AddScoped<IBarService>(di
            => new DecoratedBarService(Server.Host.Services.GetRequiredService<BarService>()));
    });            
}
```

But this surprisingly runs into the same problem.

**Attempted solution 3:**

Asking for `IBarService` instead, like this:

```
protected override void ConfigureWebHost(IWebHostBuilder builder)
{
    base.ConfigureWebHost(builder);

    builder.ConfigureTestServices(servicesConfiguration =>
    {
        servicesConfiguration.AddScoped<IBarService>(di
            => new DecoratedBarService(Server.Host.Services.GetRequiredService<IBarService>()));
    });            
}
```

Gives me a *different* error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'Cannot resolve scoped service 'Foo.Web.IBarService' from root provider.'

**Workaround A:**

I can work around the issue in my small repro like this:

```
protected override void ConfigureWebHost(IWebHostBuilder builder)
{
    base.ConfigureWebHost(builder);

    builder.ConfigureTestServices(servicesConfiguration =>
    {
        servicesConfiguration.AddScoped<IBarService>(di
            => new DecoratedBarService(new BarService()));
    });            
}
```

But this hurts *a lot* in my *actual* application, because `BarService` doesn't have a simple parameterless constructor: it has a moderately complex dependency graph, so I really would like to resolve instances from the `Startup`'s DI container.

---

PS. I've tried to make this question fully self-contained, but there's also [a clone-and-run rep(r)o](https://github.com/jeroenheijmans/sample-asp-net-core-integration-tests-di) for your convenience.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All the other answers were very helpful:

- @ChrisPratt [clearly explains](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55600576/419956) the underlying problem, and offers a solution where `Startup` makes the service registration `virtual` and then overrides that in a `TestStartup` that is forced upon the `IWebHostBuilder`
- @huysentruitw [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55600556/419956) as well that this is a limitation of the underlying default DI container
- @KirkLarkin [offers a pragmatic solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55600990/419956) where you register `BarService` itself in `Startup` and then use *that* to overwrite the `IBarService` registration completely

And still, I'd like to offer yet another answer.

The other answers helped me find the right terms to Google for. Turns out, there is [the "Scrutor" NuGet package](https://github.com/khellang/Scrutor) which adds the needed decorator support to the default DI container. You can [test this solution yourself](https://github.com/jeroenheijmans/sample-asp-net-core-integration-tests-di/compare/fix-with-nuget-package-scrutor) as it simply requires:

```
builder.ConfigureTestServices(servicesConfiguration =>
{
    // Requires "Scrutor" from NuGet:
    servicesConfiguration.Decorate<IBarService, DecoratedBarService>();
});
```

Mentioned package is open source (MIT), and you can also just adapt only the needed features yourself, thus **answering the original question as it stood, without external dependencies or changes to anything except the *test* project**:

```
public class IntegrationTestsFixture : WebApplicationFactory<Startup>
{
    protected override void ConfigureWebHost(IWebHostBuilder builder)
    {
        base.ConfigureWebHost(builder);

        builder.ConfigureTestServices(servicesConfiguration =>
        {
            // The chosen solution here is adapted from the "Scrutor" NuGet package, which
            // is MIT licensed, and can be found at: https://github.com/khellang/Scrutor
            // This solution might need further adaptation for things like open generics...

            var descriptor = servicesConfiguration.Single(s => s.ServiceType == typeof(IBarService));

            servicesConfiguration.AddScoped<IBarService>(di 
                => new DecoratedBarService(GetInstance<IBarService>(di, descriptor)));
        });
    }

    // Method loosely based on Scrutor, MIT licensed: https://github.com/khellang/Scrutor/blob/68787e28376c640589100f974a5b759444d955b3/src/Scrutor/ServiceCollectionExtensions.Decoration.cs#L319
    private static T GetInstance<T>(IServiceProvider provider, ServiceDescriptor descriptor)
    {
        if (descriptor.ImplementationInstance != null)
        {
            return (T)descriptor.ImplementationInstance;
        }

        if (descriptor.ImplementationType != null)
        {
            return (T)ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance(provider, descriptor.ImplementationType);
        }

        if (descriptor.ImplementationFactory != null)
        {
            return (T)descriptor.ImplementationFactory(provider);
        }

        throw new InvalidOperationException($"Could not create instance for {descriptor.ServiceType}");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Contrary to popular belief, the **decorator pattern** is fairly easy to implement using the built-in container.

What we generally want is to *overwrite* the registration of the regular implementation by the decorated one, *making use of the original one as a parameter to the decorator*. As a result, asking for an `IDependency` should lead to a `DecoratorImplementation` wrapping the `OriginalImplementation`.

(If we merely want to register the decorator as a *different* `TService` than the original, things are even [easier](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64116226/543814).)

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // First add the regular implementation
    services.AddSingleton<IDependency, OriginalImplementation>();

    // Wouldn't it be nice if we could do this...
    services.AddDecorator<IDependency>(
        (serviceProvider, decorated) => new DecoratorImplementation(decorated));
            
    // ...or even this?
    services.AddDecorator<IDependency, DecoratorImplementation>();
}
```

The above code works once we add the following extension methods:

```
public static class DecoratorRegistrationExtensions
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Registers a <typeparamref name="TService"/> decorator on top of the previous registration of that type.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="decoratorFactory">Constructs a new instance based on the the instance to decorate and the <see cref="IServiceProvider"/>.</param>
    /// <param name="lifetime">If no lifetime is provided, the lifetime of the previous registration is used.</param>
    public static IServiceCollection AddDecorator<TService>(
        this IServiceCollection services,
        Func<IServiceProvider, TService, TService> decoratorFactory,
        ServiceLifetime? lifetime = null)
        where TService : class
    {
        // By convention, the last registration wins
        var previousRegistration = services.LastOrDefault(
            descriptor => descriptor.ServiceType == typeof(TService));

        if (previousRegistration is null)
            throw new InvalidOperationException($"Tried to register a decorator for type {typeof(TService).Name} when no such type was registered.");

        // Get a factory to produce the original implementation
        var decoratedServiceFactory = previousRegistration.ImplementationFactory;
        if (decoratedServiceFactory is null && previousRegistration.ImplementationInstance != null)
            decoratedServiceFactory = _ => previousRegistration.ImplementationInstance;
        if (decoratedServiceFactory is null && previousRegistration.ImplementationType != null)
            decoratedServiceFactory = serviceProvider => ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance(
                serviceProvider, previousRegistration.ImplementationType, Array.Empty<object>());

        if (decoratedServiceFactory is null) // Should be impossible
            throw new Exception($"Tried to register a decorator for type {typeof(TService).Name}, but the registration being wrapped specified no implementation at all.");

        var registration = new ServiceDescriptor(
            typeof(TService), CreateDecorator, lifetime ?? previousRegistration.Lifetime);

        services.Add(registration);

        return services;

        // Local function that creates the decorator instance
        TService CreateDecorator(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
        {
            var decoratedInstance = (TService)decoratedServiceFactory(serviceProvider);
            var decorator = decoratorFactory(serviceProvider, decoratedInstance);
            return decorator;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Registers a <typeparamref name="TService"/> decorator on top of the previous registration of that type.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="lifetime">If no lifetime is provided, the lifetime of the previous registration is used.</param>
    public static IServiceCollection AddDecorator<TService, TImplementation>(
        this IServiceCollection services,
        ServiceLifetime? lifetime = null)
        where TService : class
        where TImplementation : TService
    {
        return AddDecorator<TService>(
            services,
            (serviceProvider, decoratedInstance) =>
                ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance<TImplementation>(serviceProvider, decoratedInstance),
            lifetime);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your 2nd method doesn't work `serviceProvider` and `decorated` are undefined. But the first one works well. Thank you. 
For some reasons Scrutor's AddDecorator didn't work but this one does.

Comment: @LukeP Thanks for pointing out the mistake in the bottom method. I have corrected the erroneous line. The parameterless overload should now work: `services.AddDecorator<IDependency, DecoratorImplementation>();`

Answer (score 3):

This seems like a limitation of the `servicesConfiguration.AddXxx` method which will first remove the type from the `IServiceProvider` passed to the lambda.

You can verify this by changing `servicesConfiguration.AddScoped<IBarService>(...)` to `servicesConfiguration.TryAddScoped<IBarService>(...)` and you'll see that the original `BarService.GetValue` is getting called during the test.

Additionally, you can verify this because you can resolve any other service inside the lambda except the one you're about to create/override. This is probably to avoid weird recursive resolve loops which would lead to a stack-overflow.

Comment: Thanks, with your help as well as @ChrisPratt's answer, I found that this indeed is a limitation of the default DI container. Knowing that helped me search around some more, leading to [the possible use of the "Scrutor" NuGet package](https://github.com/jeroenheijmans/sample-asp-net-core-integration-tests-di/compare/fix-with-nuget-package-scrutor) which adds this feature to the DI container.

Answer (score 3):

There's actually a few things here. First, when you register a service with an interface, you can only inject that interface. You are in fact saying: "when you see `IBarService` inject an instance of `BarService`". The service collection doesn't know anything about `BarService` itself, so you cannot inject `BarService` directly.

Which leads to the second issue. When you add your new `DecoratedBarService` registration, you now have *two* registered implementations for `IBarService`. There's no way for it to know which to actually inject in place of `IBarService`, so again: failure. Some DI containers have specialized functionality for this type of scenario, allowing you to specify when to inject which, `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection` does not. If you truly need this functionality, you can use a more advanced DI container instead, but considering this is only for testing, that would like be a mistake.

Third, you have a bit of a circular dependency here, as `DecoratedBarService` itself takes a dependency on `IBarService`. Again, a more advanced DI container can handle this sort of thing; `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection` cannot.

Your best bet here is to use an inherited `TestStartup` class and factor out this dependency registration into a protected virtual method you can override. In your `Startup` class:

```
protected virtual void AddBarService(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddScoped<IBarService, BarService>();
}
```

Then, where you were doing the registration, call this method instead:

```
AddBarService(services);
```

Next, in your test project create a `TestStartup` and inherit from your SUT project's `Startup`. Override this method there:

```
public class TestStartup : Startup
{
    protected override void AddBarService(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddScoped(_ => new DecoratedBarService(new BarService()));
    }
}
```

If you need to get dependencies in order to new up any of these classes, then you can use the passed in `IServiceProvider` instance:

```
services.AddScoped(p =>
{
    var dep = p.GetRequiredService<Dependency>();
    return new DecoratedBarService(new BarService(dep));
}
```

Finally, tell your `WebApplicationFactory` to use this `TestStartup` class. This will need to be done via the `UseStartup` method of the builder, not the generic type param of `WebApplicationFactory`. That generic type param corresponds to the entry point of the application (i.e. your SUT), not which startup class is actually used.

```
builder.UseStartup<TestStartup>();
```

Comment: I'm guessing that `BarService` has other dependencies, otherwise `new BarService()` would indeed be the way to go.

Comment: @huysentruitw Ah yes, I added such a note to my question while this answer was being written.

Comment: Either way, very helpful answer! I did indeed assume (based on working with other DI frameworks) that it would be possible, forgot to consider that the built-in DI container might just not be up to this task.

Comment: That `p` lambda param is actually an instance of `IServiceProvider`, so any other services you need to create these can be retrieved from that.

Comment: I updated my answer to give an example of retrieving a service.

Comment: Thank you once more, your answer was crucial for understanding the problem, and the offered solution is helpful too. It also helped me find/uncover [another solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55601564/419956) which I'll likely end up using, as it requires only changes to the test project by adding some "poor-man's" decorator support to the DI container.

Answer (score 2):

There's a simple alternative to this that just requires registering `BarService` with the DI container and then resolving that when performing the decoration. All it takes is updating `ConfigureTestServices` to first register `BarService` and then use the instance of `IServiceProvider` that's passed into `ConfigureTestServices` to resolve it. Here's the complete example:

```
builder.ConfigureTestServices(servicesConfiguration =>
{
    servicesConfiguration.AddScoped<BarService>();

    servicesConfiguration.AddScoped<IBarService>(di =>
        new DecoratedBarService(di.GetRequiredService<BarService>()));
});
```

Note that this doesn't require any changes to the SUT project. The call to `AddScoped<IBarService>` here effectively overrides the one provided in the `Startup` class.

Comment: This works when the decorator has no other dependencies. This gets really tiresome and error prone as the decorators become more complex (for example, a caching decorator)