# Dependency injection for Decorator pattern with multiple implementation via .Net Core 2.2, Azure Functions

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, azure-functions

I need to inject dependency in `Startup.cs`

```
 public class Startup : FunctionsStartup
    {
        public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
        {
            builder.Services.AddTransient<IAppService, AppService>();
           //how to inject for the rest
        }
    }
```

to achieve the line below:

```
   new AppService(new CacheRepository(new ConfigRepository()))
```

instead of below or others

```
   new AppService(new ConfigRepository())
```

Decorator pattern with  multiple implementation below:

```
public class ConfigRepository : IRepository
{    
    public async Task<IEnumerable<Data>> ReadDataAsync()
    {
      //...

    }
}


public class CacheRepository : IRepository
{
    private readonly IRepository _pository;   
    public CacheConfigRepository(IRepository repository)
    {
        _pository = repository;
    }
    public async Task<IEnumerable<Data>> ReadDataAsync()
    {
      //...

    }
}
```

Environment:
.Net Core 2.2, Azure Functions

**Update**

Answer:

Thanks @Timo for providing the link below
https://github.com/khellang/Scrutor

[How to overwrite a scoped service with a decorated implementation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55599360/how-to-overwrite-a-scoped-service-with-a-decorated-implementation/64116489#64116489)

Comment: What's your problem here ?

Comment: please see updated post.

Comment: You should create interfaces like IConfigRepository and ICacheRepository and they should implement IRepository. The DI should map classes to these interfaces.

Comment: You need to do `builder.Services.AddTransient` for IConfigRepository and ICacheRepository also.

Answer (score 0):

For decorating a service with a decorated cached service you can use the [Scuter](https://github.com/khellang/Scrutor).

Example:

```
public class MyService : IMyService
{    
    private readonly IRepository _repository;

    public MyService(IRepository repository)
    {
         _repository = repository;
    }
    public async Task<IEnumerable<Data>> ReadDataAsync()
    {
        //...
    }
}
```

The decorated cache service:

```
public class MyCacheService : IMyService
{
    private readonly IMyService _myService;
    private readonly ICacheRepository _cacheRepository;
    public MyCacheService(IMyService myService, ICacheRepository cacheRepository)
    {
        _myService = myService;
        _cacheRepository = cacheRepository;
    }

    public async Task<IEnumerable<Data>> ReadDataAsync()
    {
        var cachedKey = "SomeKey";
        (isCached,value) = await _cacheRepository.ReadDataAsync();
        if (isCached)
            retrun value;

        var result = await _myService.ReadDataAsync();
        return result;
    }
}
```

Startup.cs:

```
services.AddSingelton<IMyService, MyService>();
services.Decorate<IMyService, MyCacheService>();
```

Note that in this example I've added a different interface `ICacheRepository`.

Answer (score 0):

Contrary to popular belief, the **decorator pattern** is [fairly easy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64116489/543814) to implement using the built-in container.

By using the extension methods in the linked answer, registering decorators becomes as simple as this:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // First add the regular implementation
    services.AddTransient<IRepository, ConfigRepository>();
    
    // Wouldn't it be nice if we could do this...
    services.AddDecorator<IRepository>(
        (serviceProvider, wrappedRepository) => new CacheConfigRepository(wrappedRepository));
    
    // ...or even this?
    services.AddDecorator<IRepository, CacheConfigRepository>();
}
```

Comment: I updated my OP to reflect this. But I found the example on 
Scrutor is a bit different from what you provided.

Comment: @Pingpong Different? Ok, I haven't mentioned Scrutor nor know about it... Please elaborate. Also, the Scrutor link was provided by Shahar Shokrani. You could correct that in your mention in the OP.